# Error in saving animation using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I'm trying to run this particle swarm optimization code in python, I am able to run the algorithm itself but trying to save the animation of the algorithm keeps producing an error.

```py
import random
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from numpy import linspace as ls
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# Fitness function
# We assume the problem can be expressed by the following equation: 
# f(x1,x2)=(x1+2*-x2+3)^2 + (2*x1+x2-8)^2
#-20*np.exp(-0.2*(np.sqrt(0.5*(x1**2+x2**2))))-np.exp(0.5*(np.cos(2*np.pi*x1)+np.cos(2*x1*x2)))+np.exp(1)+20
# The objective is to find a minimum which is 0

def fitness_function(x1,x2):
  #f1=x1+2*-x2+3 f1**2+f2**2
  #f2=2*x1+x2-8
  z = -20*np.exp(-0.2*(np.sqrt(0.5*(x1**2+x2**2))))-np.exp(0.5*(np.cos(2*np.pi*x1)+np.cos(2*x1*x2)))+np.exp(1)+20
  return z


def update_velocity(particle, velocity, pbest, gbest, w_min=0.5, max=1.0, c=0.1):
  # Initialise new velocity array
  num_particle = len(particle)
  new_velocity = np.array([0.0 for i in range(num_particle)])
  # Randomly generate r1, r2 and inertia weight from normal distribution
  r1 = random.uniform(0,max)
  r2 = random.uniform(0,max)
  w = 1
  c1 = 1.47
  c2 = 1.62
  # Calculate new velocity
  for i in range(num_particle):
    new_velocity[i] = w*velocity[i] + c1*r1*(pbest[i]-particle[i])+c2*r2*(gbest[i]-particle[i])
  return new_velocity


def update_position(particle, velocity):
  # Move particles by adding velocity
  new_particle = particle + velocity
  return new_particle

def pso_2d(population, dimension, position_min, position_max, generation, fitness_criterion):
  # Initialisation
  global particles
  particles = [[random.uniform(position_min, position_max) for j in range(dimension)] for i in range(population)]
  # Particle's best position
  pbest_position = particles
  # Fitness
  pbest_fitness = [fitness_function(p[0],p[1]) for p in particles]
  # Index of the best particle
  gbest_index = np.argmin(pbest_fitness)
  # Global best particle position
  gbest_position = pbest_position[gbest_index]
  # Velocity (starting from 0 speed)
  velocity = [[0.0 for j in range(dimension)] for i in range(population)]
  
  # Loop for the number of generation
  for t in range(generation):
    # Stop if the average fitness value reached a predefined success criterion
    if np.average(pbest_fitness) <= fitness_criterion:
      break
    else:
      for n in range(population):
        # Update the velocity of each particle
        velocity[n] = update_velocity(particles[n], velocity[n], pbest_position[n], gbest_position)
        # Move the particles to new position
        particles[n] = update_position(particles[n], velocity[n])
    # Calculate the fitness value
    pbest_fitness = [fitness_function(p[0],p[1]) for p in particles]
    # Find the index of the best particle
    gbest_index = np.argmin(pbest_fitness)
    # Update the position of the best particle
    gbest_position = pbest_position[gbest_index]

  # Print the results
  print('Global Best Position: ', gbest_position)
  print('Best Fitness Value: ', min(pbest_fitness))
  print('Average Particle Best Fitness Value: ', np.average(pbest_fitness))
  print('Number of Generation: ', t)


population = 100
dimension = 2
position_min = -10
position_max = 10
generation = 500
fitness_criterion = 10e-8

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
x = ls(position_min, position_max,80)
y = ls(position_min, position_max,80)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = fitness_function(X,Y)
ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z, color='r', linewidth=0.2)

images=[]
image = ax.scatter3D([particles[n][0] for n in range(population)],
                     [particles[n][1] for n in range(population)],
                     [fitness_function(particles[n][0], particles[n][1]) for n in range(population)], c='b')
images.append([image])

animated_image = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, images)
animated_image.save('./pso_simple.mp4', writer='pillow')
```

The errors are:
AttributeError: 'Path3DCollection' object has no attribute '_offset_zordered'
IndexError: list index out of range

I've tried replacing it with FuncAnimation, using this line:
`animated_image = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, images, frames=list(range(1,500)), interval=500, blit=False, repeat=True)`
which has worked for a different pso code, but resulted in an error:
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable